# Why don't I get non-italic, normal font inside theorem environment using newmdtheoremenv and mdfdefinestyle?

Tags: theorems, italic

The theorem text is written in italic even if I set `font=\normalfont\normalsize`. Maybe related to that, Portuguese "-ção" is not properly recognized in that text.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}

\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\mdfdefinestyle{definitionSty}{font=\normalfont\normalsize, backgroundcolor=blue!10, linewidth=0pt, innerleftmargin=3ex, innerrightmargin=3ex, innertopmargin=3ex, innermargin =+1cm, outermargin =+1cm}

\newcounter{definitionCounter}[chapter]
\numberwithin{definitionCounter}{chapter}

\newmdtheoremenv[style=definitionSty]{definition}[definitionCounter]{Defini\c{c}\~{a}o}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}{Medição, grandeza e medida}

 \begin{itemize}
  \item medição: \textit{processo} pelo qual se mede algo
  \item grandeza: \textit{propriedade} quantificada por medição
  \item medida: \textit{resultado} do processo de medição
 \end{itemize}

\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

[image: Note that text is in italic and without sequence "çã".]

Comment: It didn't work. Besides, I'm compiling with LuaLatex and remember someone told that that command is superfluous when using that compiler. Note that the word "definição" is properly shown: that problem is only for the box text, from which I conclude that the environment redefines things. I have to type "\c{c}\~a" to have "çã".

Comment: @campa Yes, you're right! I had forgotten I had defined it that way. By the way, how do I highlight code in comments (just like you just did)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation on this is opaque, but includes an example use that starts

```
\theoremstyle{<some style>} 
\newmdtheoremenv[linecolor=blue]{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
```

The crucial thing here is the `\theoremstyle` command, which is not `mdframed` based, but refers to the `amsthm` styling commands.  So you need to load `amsthm`, and that has to be done before loading `mdframed`.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}

\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\mdfdefinestyle{definitionSty}{backgroundcolor=blue!10, linewidth=0pt, innerleftmargin=3ex, innerrightmargin=3ex, innertopmargin=3ex, innermargin =+1cm, outermargin =+1cm}

\newcounter{definitionCounter}[chapter]
\numberwithin{definitionCounter}{chapter}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newmdtheoremenv[style=definitionSty]{definition}[definitionCounter]{Defini\c{c}\~{a}o}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}Medição, grandeza e medida
 \begin{itemize}
  \item medição: \textit{processo} pelo qual se mede algo
  \item grandeza: \textit{propriedade} quantificada por medição
  \item medida: \textit{resultado} do processo de medição
 \end{itemize}
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}[Medição, grandeza e medida]\leavevmode
 \begin{itemize}
  \item medição: \textit{processo} pelo qual se mede algo
  \item grandeza: \textit{propriedade} quantificada por medição
  \item medida: \textit{resultado} do processo de medição
 \end{itemize}
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Note that I am not quite sure how I should be interpreting your argument in the definition environment.  Either print it straight as in the first version or put it in square brackets, then there is then an extra `\leavevmode` tweak needed because of the `itemize`.

Instead of loading `amsthm` you can load `ntheorem`, either with the `amsthm` option and still use `\theoremstyle`, or using its own styling commands.  You can also use the `thmtools` interfaces to either of these packages.

Comment: I've chosen `\begin{definition} \textsc{Medição, grandeza e medida} ... \end{definition}`.

Answer (score 3):

Your log will show

```
Missing character: There is no ç (U+00E7) in font cmti10!
Missing character: There is no ã (U+00E3) in font cmti10!
Missing character: There is no ç (U+00E7) in font cmti10!
Missing character: There is no ã (U+00E3) in font cmti10!
Missing character: There is no ç (U+00E7) in font cmti10!
```

If you add

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
```

Then it will use latin modern opentype fonts and the non ascii character swill work as expecteded.

Comment: Thank you, David, but I think I can't fully accept the answer because the "ç/ã" part was secondary in my question. The main subject was how to get non-italic in the theorem environment text.

Comment: @LeonardoCastro just goes to show, you shouldn't ask two questions in one question:-) I might look at the fonts later but I don't actually know the newmdtheoremenv commands so I'd have to look what it's doing.

Comment: I thought both problems were related to newmdtheoremenv reconfiguring font inside its boxes, since the problem with ç and ã didn't happen outside the boxes even without fontspec because I compiled it with LuaLaTex..